# ng-controller's contoller gives undefined when loading via RequireJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, requirejs

Iam loading the angular application using the requirejs and the ng-controller written in the main.html which loads directly but gets undefined

app.js

```
define(['sfongApp', 'ng-grid', 'angular-bootstrap'], function() {
    var sfongApp = angular.module('sfongApp', [ 'ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngGrid']);
    return sfongApp;
});
```

HTML

```
<section id="toolbar" >
<div class="adj-page" data-ng-controller="PageNavigationController"> </div>
</section>
```

PageNavigationController

```
define(['sfongApp'], function (sfongApp) {
    var pageNavigationController = function($scope) {
        ...
    };
    sfongApp.controller('PageNavigationController', ['$scope', pageNavigationController]);
    return sfongApp
});
```

The PageNavigationController mapped direclty in the HTML is not loading properly and getting undefined error. What ever is mentioned in the routes loads perfectly. Below is the error always i get.

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.5/ng/areq?p0=PageNavigationController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that `sfongApp` does not return the module try:

```
define(['angular'], function (angular) {
    var sfongApp = angular.module('sfongApp');
    var pageNavigationController = function($scope) {
        ...
    };
    sfongApp.controller('PageNavigationController', ['$scope', pageNavigationController]);

});
```

And i won't return the module as you can get it from angular and the `pageNavigationController` as i would expect this define just to load the controller on the module inside angular.

```
    require.config({
    baseUrl: '',
    paths: {
        'angular' : 'resources/script/angular.min',
        'angular-route' : 'resources/script/angular-route.min',
        'angular-bootstrap' : 'resources/script/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.9.0.min',
        'angular-animate' : 'resources/script/angular-animate',
        'angular-sanitize' : 'resources/script/angular-sanitize',
        'jquery': 'resources/script/jquery-1.9.1',
    },
    shim: {
        'sfongApp': {
            deps: [ 'jquery', 'angular', 'angular-route', 'angular-animate', 'angular-sanitize']
        },
        'angular-animate' :{
            deps: ['angular']
        },
        'angular-sanitize' : {
            deps: ['angular']
        }
    }
});

require(['sfongApp', 'PageNavigationController'], function(app) {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['sfongApp']);
});
```

Comment: i have tried that, but it dint work out, it is breaking from the html itself, even though i have removed all the functions inside the controller, it doesn't come inside itself

Comment: The error is because angular can't find the controller inside the module. So maybe the error is in the loading order of the files. I think that is possible that the  module is not created when the controller is added, please show  your requirejs config

Comment: Looks like the controller is never loaded, i updated your config